# What is $\lim _{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \tan x \sin {\frac{1}{\left| x \right| + \left| y \right|}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Fix $x=0$.

$\lim _{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \tan 0 \sin {\frac{1}{\left| y \right|}}=0$.

If this limit were to exist, then it must be $0$.

Knowing that the limit does not exist, I should try other values until I reach a contradiction.

Is there a method to help me reach the contradiction faster?

Comment: $\sin$ is a bounded function, and $\tan(x) \to 0$, so squeeze theorem says....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$\sin \frac{1}{|x| + |y|} \in [-1, 1]$$

for all $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$. Now $\tan(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, so squeeze theorem finishes the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused, are you trying to say that the limit is 0? Wolframalpha states the limit does not exist https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(x,y)+to+(0,0)+tan+x+sin+(1%2F(%7Cx%7C+%2B+%7Cy%7C))

Comment: Yes, the limit is zero. Wolfram is pretty sketchy with multivariable limits under the best of circumstances; compare [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(x,y)+to+(0,0)+tan+x+sin(1%2Fx)) to [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+tan(x)+sin(1+%2F+(x))).

Answer (score 0):

i would have multiplied and divided by $|x||y|$ and let $u= |x||y|$ you'll soon discover that you have:
$$u\tan(x) \frac{sin u}{u}$$ the latter goes to 1 while the former goes to zero as tan 0 = 0 and 0*0*0=0